# Google Sheets SUMIF with date doesn't sum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I want to sum the *amounts* column B that have a *receipt date* in column A in 2018. I tried using this [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) formula for that:

`=SUMIF(A2:A4,YEAR(2018),B2:B4)`

I expected the result to be `Fr. 5` but Google Sheet returns `0`. What am I doing wrong?

| 1 | Receipt Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 03.05.2018 | Fr. 2 |
| 3 | 07.10.2018 | Fr. 3 |
| 4 | 09.02.2019 | Fr. 5 |

(here's [a link to this example table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q1Yqe2qLnbmBRfDsZygZqYB24teZLdrMz8V0oziWQHk/edit?usp=sharing) in Google Sheets)

Additional info:

- Column A is formatted as date and column B as currency
- The date format in Switzerland is `dd.MM.yyyy`
- Google Sheet uses `Fr.` as a currency symbol for the Swiss Franc, the currency used in Switzerland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want:

- the easiest is to create a new column with =YEAR(B1), and then SUMIF using this new column as the criteria
- Alternatively, if you want to have single formula, you can use the following:

`=SUM(index(filter(a1:b3,year(a1:a3)=2018),0,2))`

- If you want to use SUMIF, you can try the following:

`=sumifs(B1:B3,A1:A3,">=1-jan-2018",A1:A3,"<=31-dec-2018")`

Comment: Hi Oren, and thanks for your suggestions! Use the link to the example table in Google Sheets to see them in action. The total with the first suggestion is `0` and the result with the second suggestion is `43383`. Unluckily none of them yielded the correct result.

Comment: In your second suggestion, the `FILTER` seems to work correctly, but I don't know what goes wrong with `INDEX` as it returns `43380` and `3`, which `SUM` then correctly adds up to `43383`.

Comment: In the first example, the filter parameter should be 2018, not YEAR(2018)

Comment: On the second one, it should be a typo..

Comment: Give me edit permissions and I’ll fix it for you

Comment: The first example now works correctly when comparing to `2018` instead of `YEAR(2018)`. Thanks!

Comment: You should have edit permissions on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q1Yqe2qLnbmBRfDsZygZqYB24teZLdrMz8V0oziWQHk/edit?usp=sharing for a while (let's see how long the Internet is nice to this spreadsheet...). :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135654/discussion-between-javier-and-oren-pinsky).

Comment: I fixed the 2nd solution in the answer